# Refactor a function - PHP

Tags: php

I have this two array of objects in this format:

```
$billsA = [{
    "key": "59",
    "amount": 81,
    "name": "CustomerA",
    "invoice_number": "10150"
  }, ...];

$billsB = [{
    "key": "59",
    "amount": 120,
    "name": "CustomerA",
    "invoice_number": "10150"
  }, ...];
```

I'm trying to compare these two arrays based on their `key` object. This function works fine if the array of objects count is about 700 but it behaves strange (ie returns inaccurate result) on bigger data. Is there any other way I can write this function beside using brute force, I just can't think of any other way :(

```
public function compareBills(array $billsA, array $billsB): array
{
    $invoiceData = [];
    foreach ($billsA as $bill_key => $billA) {
        $matchedData = [];
        foreach ($billsB as $billB) {
            if ($billA['key'] === $billB['key']) {
                if (($billB['amount'] === $billA['amount']) && (strcasecmp($billB['name'], $billA['name']) == 0)) {
                    // Remove the ones that matches
                    unset($billsA[$bill_key]);
                } else {
                    $matchedData['invoice_number'] = $billB['invoice_number'];
                    $matchedData['amount'] = ($billA['amount'] !== $billB['amount']) ? $billB['amount'] : '';
                    $matchedData['name'] = (strcasecmp($billB['name'], $billA['name']) != 0) ? $billA['name'] : '';
                    $matchedData['status'] = 'Different';
                    $invoiceData[] = $matchedData;
                    unset($billsA[$bill_key]);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    foreach ($billsA as $unmatchedData) {
        $invoiceData[] = [
            'amount' => $unmatchedData['amount'],
            'name' => $unmatchedData['name'],
            'key' => $unmatchedData['key'],
            'invoice_number' => $unmatchedData['invoice_number'],
            'status' => 'Missing',
        ];
    }
    return $invoiceData;
}
```

Comment: Would array_replace help you at all? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php - You'd just have to re-key your source arrays with the value of their `key`s, rather than having them zeo-indexed

Comment: You could filter the arrays and remove duplicated data a bit easier [like so perhaps](https://3v4l.org/TKQs6)?